# Check if a CIDR contains public IP addresses - In Java

Tags: java, networking, ip, cidr

Given a CIDR string, i would like to test whether or not this CIDR contains IP addresses that are not reserved as private addresses (i.e. is whitin one of the following ranges :)

```
192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255
172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255
10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255
```

Comment: Been awhile since I worked with CIDR, but doesnt the URI/URL classes provide functionality like this?  If you are doing it manually you could treat each octet as an order of magnitude and add them together to get give you a number: 0 + (0 * 256) + (168 * (256^2)) + (192 * (256^3))

Answer (score 2):

[Parse it into an InetAddress](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName%28java.lang.String%29), then check [its bytes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/net/InetAddress.html#getAddress%28%29).

```
int slash = cidr.indexOf('/');
String ip = cidr.substring(0, slash);
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
byte[] bytes = address.getAddress();
boolean privateAddress =
    (bytes[0] == 10) ||
    (bytes[0] == (byte) 172 && (bytes[1] >= 16 && bytes[1] < 32)) ||
    (bytes[0] == (byte) 192 && bytes[1] == (byte) 168);
```

Or, you could just check the string directly:

```
boolean privateAddress =
    cidr.startsWith("10.") || cidr.startsWith("192.168.") ||
    cidr.matches("172\\.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])\\..*");
```

Personally, I would opt for the first approach;  shorter isn’t aways better.  I’d rather rely on a parser that handles every corner case of IPv4 address notation.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up defining static CIDR blocks for private ranges and using the following code to see if it overlaps with a given CIDR - 
https://gist.github.com/nacx/8837081716c5b333d7edc8bec4684482